# 2 Questions about memory check pointing with linux kernel (custom implementation)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c

We are given a project where we implementing memory checkpointing (basic is just looking over pages and dumping data found to a file (also check info about the page (private, locked, etc)) and incremental which is where we only look at if data changed previously and dump it to a file). My understanding of this is we are pretty much building a smaller scale version of memory save states (I could be wrong but that's just what I'm getting from this). We are currently using VMA approach to our problem to go through the given range (as long as it doesn't go below or above the user space range (this means no kernel range or below user space)) in order to report the data found from the pages we encounter. I know the vma_area_struct is used to access vma (some functions including find_vma()). My issue is I'm not sure how we check the individual pages within this given range of addresses (user gives us) from using this vma_area_struct. I only know about struct page (this is pretty much it), but im still learning about the kernel in detail, so im bound to miss things. Is there something I'm missing about the vma_area_sruct when accessing pages?

Second question is, what do we use to iterate through each individual page within the found vma (from given start and end address)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMAs contain the virtual adresses of their first and (one after their) last bytes:

```
struct vm_area_struct {
     /* The first cache line has the info for VMA tree walking. */

     unsigned long vm_start;         /* Our start address within vm_mm. */
     unsigned long vm_end;           /* The first byte after our end address
                                        within vm_mm. */
...
```

This means that in order to get the page's data you need to first figure out in what context is your code running?

If it's within the process context, then a simple `copy_from_user` approach might be enough to get the actual data and a page walk (through the entirety of your PGD/PUD/PMD/PTE) to get the PFN and then turn it to a `struct page`. (Take care *not* to use the seductive `virt_to_page(addr)` as this will only work on kernel addresses).

In terms of iteration, you need only iterate in PAGE_SIZEs, over the virtual addresses you get from the VMAs.

Note that this *assumes* that the pages are actually mapped. If not (`!pte_present(pte_t a)`) you might need to remap it yourself to access the data.

If your check is running in some other context (such as a kthread/interrupt) you must remap the page from the swap before accessing it which is a whole different case. If you want the easy way, I'd look up here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html to understand how to handle swap lookup / retrieval.

Comment: Wow! I never thought about using the copy_from_user.

Comment: Well, if you're running in the same process context then that's exactly what you should do. Instead, that's the only option you have as just randomly memcpy() can be dangerous in these situations.

Comment: Wow! I never thought about using the copy_from_user. We ended up trying the approach of find_vma for the start and end address, modify the addresses with incrementing and decrementing to get a valid vma range (if available), then walk through the pages and dumping findings to a file. We did okay, but it failed on the range (0, 0xfffffff) (full dump). We then tried similar approach with incremental check pointing (only checking PageDirty()), but it failed.

Comment: Well, how did you read the data itself? I hate betting but I think it'd be something with mapping which copy_from_user will solve.

Comment: follow_page and linked list

Comment: Our dump file did have a lot of 0x0 pages

Comment: Well this is because 0 pages might be accessible through kernel but they are not actually mapped. Be careful with that as you might raise a page fault in kernel (which is a bad idea generally).